# Having trouble with C# Properties, Constructors,and LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

The code below is not returning any values. I am trying to print customer name and balance where their balance is below $0. I believe my property may not be set the right way. I am new to object oriented programming and LINQ. Any help would be appreciable.

```
namespace LinqExample
{
    class Customer
    {
        private string name, phone, address;
        private int balance;
        public string custData;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { name = value; }
        }

        public string Phone
        {
            get { return phone; }
            set { phone = value; }
        }

        public string Address
        {
            get { return address; }
            set { address = value; }
        }

        public int Balance
        {
            get { return balance; }
            set { balance = value; }
        }

        public Customer(string name, string phone, string address, int balance)
        {
            custData = name + phone + address + balance;
        }
    }
}

namespace LinqExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>();

            customers.Add(new Customer("Amit", "123-456-789", "123 Any Road", 25));
            customers.Add(new Customer("Ajay", "571-888-1234", "1234 Any Street", 50));
            customers.Add(new Customer("John", "707-123-4560", "456 John Street", -10));
            customers.Add(new Customer("Ashley", "707-123-8402", "789 Ashley Street", -20));

            var overdue =
                from cust in customers
                where cust.Balance < 0
                orderby cust.Balance ascending
                select new { cust.Name, cust.Balance };

            foreach (var cust in overdue)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Name = {cust.Name}, Balance = {cust.Balance}");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not set any values in those property!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the members values:

```
    public Customer(string name, string phone, string address, int balance)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.address = address;
        this.balance = balance;
        custData = name + phone + address + balance;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not setting any of your properties other than "custdata", you need to set the rest of the properties in your constructor too.

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated you're not assigning any of your properties to the passed in ctor values. 
Either do what Romano suggested or use an object initializer.

**Assign the properties in the constructor.**

```
 public Customer(string name, string phone, string address, int balance)
 {
      this.name = name;
      this.phone = phone;
      this.address = address;
      this.balance = balance;
      custData = name + phone + address + balance;
 }
```

**Object Initilizer with a default ctor.**

```
customers.Add(new Customer
{ 
  Name = "Bill", 
  Phone = "555-555-5555",
  Address = "2345 Some street",
  Balance = "100000000"
});
```

As a side note, instead of using that public field "custData" try overriding the ToString method to return all of that concatenated data.